# Sounds skips in window 8

Tags: windows-8, audio

If I'm watching a video and I paused it and then I unpaused it, if the volume was set high it'll skip to a lower setting and vice versa. But once push the volume keys up or down, it'll go back to the setting it was suppose to be at.

Comment: What kind of sound card are you using? Have you tried to update the drivers? Have you tried anything else, e.g. changing out speakers, etc?

Comment: I don't really know what kind of sound card I have. I'm using a laptop. And it seems that everything is updated already.

Comment: So built in hardware and speakers... so doesn't sound like you'd be able replace them easily. You can try to look at event logs and such, but that would just give you info to report then you'd have to wait for a driver patch, if that is the issue... may want to consider installing Windows 7 or maybe kubuntu on the system if those are options.

Comment: I'll guess I just leave it the way it is then. It's not a big deal since all I have to do is push one key to fix it. Plus it seems that whenever I change anything else other issues pops up. Thanks for helping.